# Full range of values - matlab

Tags: matlab, range, histogram, bin

I have got the following results after using `[h, bins] = hist(H)` in `matlab`:

```
h =

   221    20     6     4     1     1     2     0     0     1


bins =

  Columns 1 through 7

    8.2500   24.7500   41.2500   57.7500   74.2500   90.7500  107.2500

  Columns 8 through 10

  123.7500  140.2500  156.7500
```

- How do I know the **full range** of values? Especially that I expected to have up to `255`, that is `[0,255], and if we analyze the range of the bins below we will have the following for the ten bins respectively:

0-16.5
16.5-33
33-49.5
49.5-66
66-82.5
82.5-99
99-115.5
115.5-132
132-148.5
148.5-165

So, did I get this range *only* due to having only 10 bins?

Thanks.

Comment: You can get the full range with `max(H)` and `min(H)`.  If you want to specify the bin locations for `hist` you can do that with a second vector argument.

Comment: an/or take a look at `histc`; it allows you to specify the bin edges (instead of bin centres)

Comment: I think this gives us the range of the `frequencies` and not the range of the values on the x-axis?

Answer (score 1):

yes, the 10 bins are the default of `hist`. If you know you might have values between [0,255]  you can force whatever bin positions you want, for example:

```
[h, bins] = hist(H,0:255)
```

will create 256 bins each for each integer value [0,255]